# Retrofit returns empty when transfering JSON objects to a class array

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to transfer the info I get from "response" into a class array. Buy after the program runs, even though I added the strings into my own array, the items somehow get deleted and my list becomes empty for some reason. Cannot figure out why.

I've tried adding the strings on a for loop. It works up until retrofil enqueue function finishes up, then the list becomes empty all of a sudden.

**My JSonPlaceHolderApi Class**

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("A.txt")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();
}
```

**My POST Class for getting JSON formatted objects**

```
public class Post {

    //JSON Object Variables
    @SerializedName("Code")
    private String lecCode;

    //Getters
    public String getLecCode() {
        return lecCode;
    }
}
```

**My global class array**

```
ArrayList<String> lecCodesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**My Main Activity**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(myBaseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                List<Post> posts = response.body();

                for(Post post : posts){
                    lecCodesList.add(post.getLecCode());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ERROR", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I've tried debugging and when the program is inside the call enqueue section, the array gets populated correctly. But the second enqueue function ends, lecCodesList becomes empty for some reason. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When do you use `lecCodesList`?

Comment: @faranjit I'm passing that to my RecyclerView to list them on screen.

Comment: I mean do you use it before response come to `onResponse` or after? If answer is before, it is normal to be empty.

Comment: @faranjit I use it after. I need to display the contents of the posts on the screen and I thought I'd just transfer them to an array to keep them. Why does the array become empty though? It's a class array and has nothing to do with retrofit?

Comment: Can you post whole activity?

Comment: @faranjit this is all of it. Than I pass that array to my RecyclerView and the program ends. I've tried with a temp array to see if RecyclerView was the problem but it's not. It is definitely the retrofit. Because when I debugged it, the lecCodesList would populate properly one by one but the second it jumps out of enqueue, that array goes back to being empty. That's what I'm trying to figure out.